# Easier way of passing QString for Object::tr?

Tags: c++, qt

I want my app to be multilangual. That's why I use `Object::tr` for every string in my app. Its easy, when I have this:

`QObject::tr("message");`

but having QString for `QObject::tr` is quite long:

```
    QString msg = "";
    msg += "some kind of message";

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText(QObject::tr(msg.toStdString().c_str()));
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    msgBox.exec();
```

can it be done easier?

Comment: There is usually no need to translate `QString`. In your example you should use `msg += tr("some kind of message")` instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just pass `QString` through [`qPrintable`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#qPrintable) to the `QObject::tr`.

```
QString msg = "";
msg += "some kind of message";

QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText(QObject::tr(qPrintable(msg)));
msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
msgBox.exec();
```